# getting 404 for get api controller result after changing startup to OWIN

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I start with Empty asp.net web api application with all default settings for VS 2017. I added one controller method with httpGet and result is fine.

Now I installed `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` and added a OWIN `Startup`class.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebApp1.Startup))]

namespace WebApp1
{
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
}
```

After that I comment out `global.asax` code as I believe I don't need it,

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
```

Removing as well below code for  Web API routes

```
 //public static class WebApiConfig
//{
//    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
//    {
//        // Web API configuration and services

//        // Web API routes
//        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

//        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
//            name: "DefaultApi",
//            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
//            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
//        );
//    }
//}
```

Now I'm getting 404 error while accessing the API, my OWIN startup code also calling. Whats wrong here? please suggest!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the following line of code at the end of your OWIN **Configuration** method:

```
app.UseWebApi(config);
```

Note: this method is located in:

```
using Owin; //Assembly System.Web.Http.Owin
```

Comment: Thanks, it's works, I have also added `AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost` package.

Comment: @user584018 That's great, to avoid cross-origin error I recommend you to add this line as well (before UserWebApi()) add
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);